# Google Maps Static API Load Denied by X-Frame

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I have recently set up a Google Static Maps API and I am now trying to implement this into my site.  I am trying to host it on an Iframe and the map information will then change depending on what the user inputs for their search criteria.

However, I am getting the "Load denied by X-Frame" error in my console.

I have tried all the solutions at [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) but nothing seems to work.  I've tried using both a browser and server API key, http & https but still nothing.

Why oh why do google have to make it so complicated???

Can anyone give me some pointers in how to get a map which is intended for use by google in my site, to actually display in my site??

Comment: What Google Maps API that you enable in your developers console?

Comment: Google Static Maps API

Comment: I think the "DON'T FRAME THEM" comment by Marc B is pretty clear. If you disagree, I recommend filing a feature request for the API to drop that header: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Static%20Maps%20-%20Feature%20Request

Comment: So how do I get a map to display within my site then?